# SQL Server Maintenance Plan Not working - no errors

Tags: sql, sql-server

To put it simply. I have a SQL Server maintenance plan scheduled to run every Sunday at 8:02 am. This morning when I checked the jobs it says it was successful but it didn't actually run (yesterday on 5/20) it is still showing the successful message from the previous run on 5/13. The job is enabled and I cant find any errors associated with it in the logs. A bit stumped.

Comment: is the "schedule" also enabled?

Comment: Yes the schedule is enabled.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: kk thanks. Sorry was just hoping someone else has seen this/had this happen to them.

Comment: Check if it's still running. The log at SSMS history won't show up if the job is still running at the first step.

Comment: It is not. Is currently idle.